# Diferença entre :80 e as demais portas

Tags: http, desempenho

Estou com um problema de hospedagem onde não poderei subir minha aplicação na porta padrão `:80`, como solução apresentada me indicaram subi-la em uma porta diferente, exemplo `:3000`, e fazer o direcionamento do link para a determinada porta. Perguntas:

1. A performance será alterada? Por conta de não ser a porta padrão de acesso.
2. O site pode ser bloqueado por conta de estar acessando uma porta não padrão em alguns casos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A performance será alterada? Por conta de não ser a porta padrão de acesso.

Se acessar direto não haverá perda de performance.

Mas se alguém pegar esse endereço e acabar descuidadamente tirar a porta vai dar problema.

> O site pode ser bloqueado por conta de estar acessando uma porta não padrão em alguns casos?

Sim, em muitos lugares só a porta 80 pode ser acessada, um dos motivos de se fazer para web (o protocolo, não a UI).

Acho estranho ter essa limitação. Não sei o contexto, mas considere trocar de provedor se não houver solução por parte deles.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).